# Allow special characters and spaces in text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have this text field where allowing only characters

I want to allow special characters and space in the same onkeypress event.

```html
 <input maxlength="30" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="30" formControlName="Name"
 onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)">
```

Comment: you can add more conditions like || (event.charCode == 32) || (event.charCode == 33) for all the special character you want to allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more concise approach would be to use a regex to match the allowed characters instead of listing them manually. Something like:

```js
function validateInput(event) {
    // You can add other special characters(I might have missed) based on your requirement.
    const regex = /[A-Za-z\s!@#$%^&[\];':",.\/<>?\\-]/;
    const char = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    return regex.test(char);
  }
```

```html
<input maxlength="30" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return validateInput(event);" formControlName="Name" />
```

Answer (score 2):

As @mandy8055 suggested, you can use a regex.
I would personally use an eventListener, but also use the regex to remove pasted content.

Remember to repeat the tests on the server since a user can easily bypass client validation

```js
const regex = /[A-Za-z\s!@#$%^&[\];':",.\/<>?\\-]/;
const validateInput = (event) =>  regex.test(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));
const filterInput = (input) => input.value.split('').filter(char => regex.test(char)).join('');

const input = document.querySelector('[formControlName=Name]');
input.addEventListener('keypress', validateInput)
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => e.target.value = filterInput(e.target));
```

```html
<input maxlength="30" class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="Name" />
```